# Why do some of the functions in the OpenCV C++ interface have struct declarations in them?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I saw these two similiar/same functions  on [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html?highlight=cvsvm#bool%20CvSVM%3a%3atrain%28const%20CvMat%2a%20trainData,%20const%20CvMat%2a%20responses,%20const%20CvMat%2a%20varIdx,%20const%20CvMat%2a%20sampleIdx,%20CvSVMParams%20params%29)
 under the [CvSVM::train](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html?highlight=cvsvm#cvsvm-train) heading

```
C++: bool CvSVM::train(const Mat& trainData, const Mat& responses, 
const Mat& varIdx=Mat(), const Mat& sampleIdx=Mat(), CvSVMParams 
params=CvSVMParams() )

C++: bool CvSVM::train(const CvMat* trainData, const CvMat* responses, 
const CvMat* varIdx=0, const CvMat* sampleIdx=0, CvSVMParams params=CvSVMParams() )
```

They are the same but one uses the `const Mat&` and the other `CvMat*`.

I am writing a wrapper for OpenCV and I was wondering if, to make it complete:

- would I need to include all the C structs?
- Or can C++ use the C structs?
- Or is CvMat and other structs both C and C++?

I was under the impression that C++ used classes and C structs in OpenCV but if someone could shed light on this I would appreciate that.

Also in the OpenCV cpp samples folder letter_recog.cpp there is alot of CvMat* in it. Rs that code just old and hasnt been updated yet?

Opencv docs say CvMat is deprecated.

- So of the two above functions should I just use the const Mat& one?
- And assume OpenCv documentation though posted on website is still maybe a bit "in proccess"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CvMat` version is just for interfacing to old code.
CvSVM internally uses CvMat so your first function above simply converts the Mat arguments to CvMat and passes them to the second function.

I am not sure what you mean by "writing a wrapper for OpenCV" but unless you have an explicit need to use CvMat, only use Mat. Once you include CvMat in your wrapper and someone uses it, it will be difficult to later get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for that answer that really saved me time... so  is the letter_recog.cpp described in my post just old code that hasn't been converted to all C++ yet?

Comment: Yes, the giveaway is the include on the first line "opencv2/core/core_c.h". Since it works I don't guess it will get converted for a while if ever (it is still there in the 3.0 src). Trouble is it makes it difficult for people that  are starting out, and those that aren't are not going to really look at the samples. They probably should be in a folder called junk.